# Finding a Basis of $V= \{3\times 3 real matrices\}$, consisting of symmetric or skew symmetric matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$V$ is the direct sum of two vector spaces $V_1$ and $V_2$, where $$V_1= \mathrm{span} (e_{1,1}, ~e_{1,3}, ~e_{2,2},~ e_{3,1},~e_{3,3})$$ $$V_2 =   \mathrm{span}(e_{1,2},~e_{2,1},~ e_{2,3},~ e_{3,2}) $$
( $e_{1,1}, ~... ~,e_{3,3}$) as a standard basis of V, and indexing $i,j$ meaning$i,j$ th entries)

I could directly use $V_1$'s spanning set for an answer, but elements of the $V_2$'s spanning set aren't symmetric/skew symmetric so I can't use them.  So I need to think of some new basis for $V_2$ but couldn't find one. I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=3$ and your base be $\text{Sy}\cup\text{Sk}$, where

$$\text{Sy}=\{e_{ii}\,|\,i=1,..,n\}\cup\{e_{ij}+e_{ji}\,|\,1\leq i<j\leq n\}$$

and

$$\text{Sk}=\{e_{ij}-e_{ji}\,|\,1\leq i<j\leq n\}.$$